# CSS / HTML Background color for a div not reaching bottom of page when height = 100%?

Tags: html, css, navigationbar

My sidebar for a website I'm trying to make is supposed to reach the bottom of the page regardless of how you resize the page, and it worked for a week until now when for some reason the bottom-left is poking out like so: [image of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cf7BZ.jpg).

The code for this sidebar css is:

```
.sidebar {
    width: 220px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #262626;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

You can see that the height is at 100%, and it stretches all the way in the past but now there is some white where the sidebar is not reaching clearly (check the image, bottom left). I feel like this problem started when I added a `div` to the right as a sub-header, as you can see in the image right now its showing "Sample Catalog Items". The content section below this "Sample Catalog Items" `div` is named content in my css and the code also sets its height to 100%:

```
.content {
    width: auto;
    margin-left: 220px; /* same as side bar to bring content to the right place */
    height: 100%;
    backgrouond-color: #030303;
    /* then add padding */
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    background-color: #bdc3c7;
}
```

The aforementioned `div`'s css code is:

```
.sub_header {
    font-size: 1.7em;
    margin-left: 220px;
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: #7f8c8d;

}
```

I feel like this `div` is making the `.sidebar` stick out next to `.content`, and I've tried numerous ways to look this up and fix it but I can't figure it out. Doesn't `height: 100%` mean it will stretch all the way even if there are more `div`s on the other side?

Comment: Can you create a fiddle? We can't guess your html structure

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xw80wsqm/ like this? When I run it there it's hard to tell if there is white sticking out cuz the window is too small.

Comment: Do you want the content to scroll when page overflow or all page? ... Also, post your markup

Comment: Hmm I want content to not all appear on one page, and appear as I scroll down if they are more than one page. But I want the sidebar to stretch to the bottom, no matter how much "content" there is, the side bar on the left should always reach the bottom. I see some people have told me to put ".sub_header" in ".content" or their heights are added and not the same 100% as the side bar's height: 100%.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since I can't see the html, I'll suggest a couple of things that might be a problem:

1. if the `.sub_header` is not inside `.content`, they both sum up to a height bigger then 100% of the body height. That's why those two elements take a total bigger than the sidebar.
2. if you know in advance that you want elements to spread all over the screen, it might be better to use `100vh` instead of `100%`. (100vh = 100 * 1% of the **viewport height**)
3. make sure you set `box-sizing: border-box` on your elements so that you'll get the size you expect. Most people tend to think in the way `box-sizing: border-box` work and not as the default behaviour. [Here's](https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/) a little article explaining `box-sizing: border-box`.

Here's a little example:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.sidebar {
  width: 220px;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #262626;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.content {
  width: auto;
  margin-left: 220px;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  background-color: #bdc3c7;
}

.sub_header {
  font-size: 1.7em;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: #7f8c8d;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">.sidebar</div>
<div class="content">
  <div class="sub_header">.sub_header</div>
  .content
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

See comments below for clarification.

Old answer:
Try specifying the height of the body as 100% too like this:

```
.body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Make sure to put this above the sidebar section.

Comment: That still doesn't fix it. The main "body" is already at 100% with from the `.content` `div` I think, there were no changes when I put `height: 100%` for `body`. I put the html and css here: https://jsfiddle.net/xw80wsqm/. I still got more pages but I don't want to put all the code unless it's absolutely needed, the code is similar to the posted page though.

Comment: Because you have the sidebar set at 100% and the content set at 100%, when you insert another div (the subheading) above the content it's pushing it down. You'll need to put the subheading div inside your content div and then remove some of the padding/margins you have set to position it how you want.

Comment: Ok I see it now, that is a bit weird though because I assumed 100% meant 100% stretch the whole way, no matter how long the other sides are... I mean 100% + a div should still = 100% you know? 100% is 100%. That's why I was so confused. I'll try fix it and come back if there are problems thank you!

Comment: Yeh, I wish that were the case. But percentage based sizes use the parent's sizings as a base. So if you have a div with height 300px, and create 2 divs inside it with height 100%, they will both be 300px high.

Comment: Try using you browsers developers tool to inspect element

Answer (score 1):

What happens is as that your `sub_header`'s height is added to the `content`'s, hence they together becomes more than 100% of their parent.

One solution is to give the `sub_header` a fixed height and subtract that from the `content`, so if you update these 2 rules with this

```
.content {
    height: calc(100% - 70px);
}

.sub_header {
    height: 70px;
}
```

Sample

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans");

/* general */

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

#header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 75px;
    background-color: #34495e;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.logo {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    padding-top: 6px;
    color: #ffffff;
}
.logo a {
    font-size: 1.9em;
    color: #ffffff;

}

#container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.sidebar {
    width: 220px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #262626;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    color: #ffffff;
}

ul {

}
#sidebar li {
    list-style: none;

}
#sidebar li a {
    color: #cccccc; /* grey */
    display: block; /* default for most elements, but overrides in this case */
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 1em;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: 0.3s;
    transition: 0.4s; /* however effects delay */
}
#sidebar li a:hover {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #030303;
    padding-left: 25px; /* shifts sidebar elements on hover */
}


.content {
    margin-left: 220px; /* same as side bar to bring content to the right place */
    height: calc(100% - 70px);
    backgrouond-color: #030303;
    /* then add padding */
    padding: 15px;
    /* padding-top: 15px; */
    font-size: 1.1em;
    background-color: #bdc3c7;
}


/* sub pages */

.sub_header {
    font-size: 1.7em;
    margin-left: 220px;
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: #7f8c8d;
    height: 70px;
}
#contact_info {
    margin-left: 220px;
    font-size: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
    <div class="logo"> <!-- Logo of Website -->
        <a href="#">Everyshine Impex Limited<span> <!-- Source --></span></a> <!-- Span for endline element -->
    </div>

</div>

<div id="container">
    <!-- 245px for menu bar -->
    <div class="sidebar">
        <ul id="sidebar">
            <li><a class="selected" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="about us.html">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="catalog items.html">Catalog Items</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Information</a></li>

        </ul>

    </div>

    <div class="sub_header">
    Sample Catalog Items
    </div>

    <div class="content">
        Catalog Items

    </div>

</div>
```

---

The downside with the above is on smaller screen, `sub_header` text might not fit and it will look odd. To deal with that you can use a media query, but a more clever approach would be to use `flexbox`, so add a `wrapper` in your markup around `sub_header`/`content` like this,

```
<div class="wrapper">        
  <div class="sub_header">
    Sample Catalog Items
  </div>

  <div class="content">
    Catalog Items
  </div>
</div>
```

and add/update these rules like this

```
.wrapper {
    margin-left: 220px; /* same as side bar to bring content to the right place */
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.content {
    flex: 1;
    background-color: #030303;
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    background-color: #bdc3c7;
}


/* sub pages */

.sub_header {
    font-size: 1.7em;
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: #7f8c8d;
}
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans");

/* general */

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

#header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 75px;
    background-color: #34495e;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.logo {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    padding-top: 6px;
    color: #ffffff;
}
.logo a {
    font-size: 1.9em;
    color: #ffffff;

}

#container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.sidebar {
    width: 220px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #262626;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    color: #ffffff;
}

ul {

}
#sidebar li {
    list-style: none;

}
#sidebar li a {
    color: #cccccc; /* grey */
    display: block; /* default for most elements, but overrides in this case */
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 1em;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: 0.3s;
    transition: 0.4s; /* however effects delay */
}
#sidebar li a:hover {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #030303;
    padding-left: 25px; /* shifts sidebar elements on hover */
}

.wrapper {
    margin-left: 220px; /* same as side bar to bring content to the right place */
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.content {
    flex: 1;
    background-color: #030303;
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    background-color: #bdc3c7;
}


/* sub pages */

.sub_header {
    font-size: 1.7em;
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: #7f8c8d;
}
#contact_info {
    margin-left: 220px;
    font-size: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
    <div class="logo"> <!-- Logo of Website -->
        <a href="#">Everyshine Impex Limited<span> <!-- Source --></span></a> <!-- Span for endline element -->
    </div>

</div>

<div id="container">
    <!-- 245px for menu bar -->
    <div class="sidebar">
        <ul id="sidebar">
            <li><a class="selected" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="about us.html">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="catalog items.html">Catalog Items</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Information</a></li>

        </ul>

    </div>

    <div class="wrapper">
    
      <div class="sub_header">
        Sample Catalog Items
      </div>

      <div class="content">
        Catalog Items

      </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

---

Note, for percent based height on elements, all parents, all the way up to the `html`/`body` need a height, and in your case this update will be enough

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

---

Another observation is you use `float` on the `logo` and the `sidebar`. When using floats one sometimes need to clear them, or else they might cause problems later on, when/if you add more elements to their parent.

If that occurs, here is how you can clear them, based on your existing markup

```
#header::after,
#container::after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this answer has been extremely in-depth and helpful, I'm trying the different solutions I'll post if I need more help

Comment: @Darkphoton The 2 given options is probably the best there is, to keep equal height columns _and_ a responsive layout structure ... well, there is the old trick using `display: table` if you need dynamic height on the `sub_header` and to support older browsers

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and it's because height value doesn't adapt dinamically with the scroll.

One posible solution is use "position" instead of "float"...

```
.sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 220px;
    background-color: #262626;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.content {
    position: absolute; 
    width: auto;
    left: 220px;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #030303;
    /* then add padding */
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    background-color: #bdc3c7;
}
```

This should work...

Comment: It worked in that it stretches all the way, but the entire sidebar moves down with the scroll bar now leaving whites above!

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it... Can you show me a picture?

Comment: And sorry, I forgot to mention that with this solution the sidebar will stay fixed and won't scroll (is the "leaving whites above" what I don't get).

If you need your sidebar to scroll with the page, another posible solution will be to establish the background color of <body> to the sidebar background color, then you establlsh the background of "content" to your desired color and set height 100%. In case "content" grows, you'll still see sidebar color correctly (because its the <body> color)

Comment: No problem, what I meant was now the side bar fixed my problem and it stretches all the way, but when I scroll down, the side bar comes down with the page. So I can see empty space above as sidebar is coming down the page as I scroll.

Comment: Mmm... that's strange... sidebar should be completely fixed when you scroll... 

I assume you mean the menu is moving, right? (.sidebar is just the container of the menu)? That's maybe because of the css of the menu. I don't know how are you defining the menu (nav, ul, divs, etc.), can you post the menu css?